# How to add an intro movie to my app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, quicktime, movie, movieplayer

I have a quicktime movie that I would like to appear when the user starts my app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a splash screen which shows a movie. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575273/iphone-showing-video-as-a-splash-screen) shows some basic code. Also see [Application Launch Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12).

Related:

- [How to add animated splash screen in our application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219283/how-to-add-animated-splash-screen-in-our-application)
- [Is it a good idea to use an video as splash screen in my iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431762/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-an-video-as-splash-screen-in-my-iphone-app)
- [play movie file during iphone application startup(i.e during application loading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342383/play-movie-file-during-iphone-application-startupi-e-during-application-loading)